# NetLogo: procedure for performing an operation on one item in a list in a compact way?

Tags: netlogo

New to NetLogo... wondering if there's a procedure that performs an operation on one item in a list in a compact way (like map but for one item).

For example, say I wanted to add `3` to the item at index `i` in list `blah`.

Right now I'm doing this like:

`set blah replace-item i blah (item i blah + 3)`

It seems a little clunky, and like there would be a procedure that does that, but I haven't been able to find one. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Thank you!
Taylor

Answer (score 1):

There isn't something built in that does this.  But you could define it yourself as a procedure that takes a task as input:

```
;; replace item i of xs with the result of applying fn to that item
to-report mapping-replace-item [i xs fn]
  report replace-item i xs (runresult fn item i xs)
end
```

Sample usage:

```
observer> show mapping-replace-item 2 [10 20 30 40] task [? * ?]
observer: [10 20 900 40]
```