# NetLogo - Add a single value to a list of lists

Tags: list, addition, netlogo, items

I'm trying to enter a value into a list of lists when necessary.

I define a list globally:

```
set mylist [[[][]][[][]]]
```

At various stages of the simulation, I wish to have an agent insert a value into the list (these values will make up their own lists). For example, if I wanted to add the value 2 to item 0 of item 1, I'd put:

```
....
set item 0 item 1 mylist lput 2 item 0 item 1 mylist
....
```

Which returns the error message "This isn't something you can use "set" on." Any help? I seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about adding to lists.

FYI my inteded return for the example above would be for mylist to become:

```
[[[][]][[2][]]]
```

(And a different agent would have the opportunity to add another value to item 0 of item 1 later in the simulation if needed).

Thanks

Comment: You need `replace-item`. Note that `replace-item` returns a new list; NetLogo lists are immutable, so you need `set mylist replace-item ...`

Comment: possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23182872/86485, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21354589/86485

Comment: Thanks for the response. This covers replacing an item in the list, but is it possible to add an item to the list (with lput) rather than replacing it altogether? This is where I'm still stuck.

Comment: Have you considered the table extension?  Accessing your lists by key instead of by location may be more intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetLogo lists are immutable, which means you can never actually alter an existing list, only make a new one.  If you want to modify mylist, you need to `set mylist ...` where `...` is a new list you've just constructed.

To make a new list based on old list, except for swapping in a different value in one place, well, that's what `replace-item` does.

But `replace-item` doesn't know about nesting, so we have to handle that ourselves, by calling `replace-item` twice, once for the inner list, and once for the outer list.

I'll assume your list has a fixed nesting depth of 2 and you don't need to handle arbitrary nesting depths.

The first building block we need, we can copy verbatim from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23256444/86485 :

```
to-report replace-subitem [index1 index2 lists value]
  let old-sublist item index1 lists
  report replace-item index1 lists (replace-item index2 old-sublist value)
end
```

Now in order to solve your problem we only need to do a little extra work:

```
to-report lput-subitem [index1 index2 lists value]
  report replace-subitem index1 index2 lists
           lput value (item index2 item index1 lists)
end
```

Let's take it for a spin:

```
observer> set mylist [[[][]][[][]]]
observer> print mylist
[[[] []] [[] []]]
observer> set mylist lput-subitem 1 0 mylist 2
observer> set mylist lput-subitem 1 0 mylist 3
observer> print mylist
[[[] []] [[2 3] []]]
```

It works!